# How to deploy Spring application with several services launching by Docker in AWS?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, docker

I created simple Spring Boot app that depends on several services launching in Docker (Cashe, MessageBroker, Database ...). In future I want to add some other services, my custom or from Docker images. How can I deploy this stack of services in AWS?
In tutorials there are only examples of connecting to RDS.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for CloudFormation or using the AWS CDK?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/). That is, create a Docker image from your Spring Boot project. Then, you can deploy your Docker image to Docker Hub, which is a hosted repository service. Finally, configure AWS Fargate to import the Docker image located on Docker Hub into a container, as shown in the following illustration.

[image]

Here is step by step for this [use case](https://scottscloudcommunity.blogspot.com/2022/10/deploying-java-web-application-to.html).